# Rake db:migrate fails on devise User using mysql db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

So i am following the process based on Devise read.me Getting Started. This is the process i did

Created my rails project
Added gem 'devise'
rake db:create
rails generate devise:install
Added home#index to routes
added action_mailer_deafult_url_options to development.rb
rails generate devise User
rake db:migrate when i run rake db:migrate, it fails and gives me this error report

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

super: no superclass method sanitize_for_mass_assignment' for #<ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration version: nil> NoMethodError: super: no superclass methodsanitize_for_mass_assignment' for #
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :registerable

end
```

migration file

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Does anyone know any reason why this is happening

I am using rails - 4.2.3 and Devise 3.5.2

Comment: What does your `user.rb` model look like?

Comment: added d model @DustinFisher

Comment: Can you also include the migration?

Comment: This is why I used to put the link for the github repo to show the whole picture, but one of the "powerful" guys with down-voting privileges told me I can't do that.

Comment: @RichardSeviora added the migration file

Comment: Huh. That didn't explain anything at all. Fun! We need to see the trace to continue debugging this, so lets get it. Try running it as: `bundle exec rake ---trace db:migrate`. And then post the backtrace when it fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issues and you have installed gem 'strong_parameters' please remove it because it has been added in ActiveModel and ActiveController since Rails 4.0. Documentation got me confused so i added the gem and tht caused my error.